# MKS integration with Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, mks, mks-integrity

I was searching for options for a plugin for MKS version control within Visual Studio 2008.  I found the main website mentioning a plugin availible, but so far it sounds like it was orginaly for visual studio 2005.  Is there any confirmation that it works ok with visual studio 2008 also?  I assume it might work fine, but I have not seen any official docs or seen anything talking about plugin success with visual studio 2008.

So, to sum up the question. Does the MKS visual studio plugin work with 2008?

MKS Integrity is the system in place at this company, so I can't move to SVN or other version control systems.

http://www.mks.com/solutions/microsoft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/rn/relnotes_tk92p3.asp#92p3_intro

I guess I answered my own question.  Now I found the release notes mentioning visual studio 2008 exactly.

Answer (score 2):

We are also using MKS integration with Visual Studio 2008. It's kind of let's say "supported". Working with the MKS integration for Visual Studio doesn't make fun because it does not register as SCM-plugin in Visual Studio. Instead it is calling the normal MKS Client via Command Line. This really sucks because some Windows and Popups are always hidden in background an block the Visual Studio Process.
MKS really has the worst integration i have ever seen :( Maybe its good for other IDEs, but not the tool of choice for VS Develpers.

Comment: Maybe I will just stay away from it then and just continue to use the Integrity Client.

Answer (score 2):

MKS is the worst possible choice for working under Visual Studio.
Their "integration solution" generally is not compatible with normal development.
They have their own UI application working in background, which is "trying" to communicate with Visual studio environment.

What is worst, the MKS "project" is not the same as Visual Studio project. The solution file - just a file, not a reference to the projects.

Comment: Believe me, I am currently not a fan of MKS after the last couple years. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the 2003 integration with VS2003, VS2005, VS2008 and VS2010 and haven't had any problems.  I actually like the fact the MKS screens are triggered the same whether from within VS or outside. The only minor issue was changing the setting to supress the redundant VS "check in comment" dialog. However, VS "checked out list" panel works fine and the solution browser panel indicates items that are checkout or new members that need to be added. Context menus have added choices to show file history or differences from the checked-in version. It honestly seems to me exactly how 3rd party source code integration is supposed to work.